# Flutter http API calls

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

How can I setup a framework for API calling in flutter ?

Instead of just creating a api call function need to create a  framework that can be used for multiple future projects

Comment: Awesome idea by the way, Could you support your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate project for API calls and models, this project will include the model classes and services for API calls. For API calls you can use retrofit or dio, whatever you want to use. This project will not include the UI, make the project by following command.

```
flutter create --template=package api_framework
```

Now you can include this framework project in many projects you want. Just add the path of this project in `pubspec.yaml` as following

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  api_fremework:
    path: ./api_framework
```

Now you will be able to call the API functions.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dio or any other libraries then the best way is to make a Dio helper class where you can change only the BASE_URL and will be globally used in all other classes after step by step you can add the not changeable things there.

I hope it helps

Comment: Can you share any documentation regarding the dio helper class ?

Comment: please check this link for a project has a Dio helper class https://gist.github.com/RyanDsilva/ee205c02f98df9f830dcd9034e9a5e9b

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

> ```
> import 'dart:convert';
>
> import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:http/http.dart';
>
> class callapi extends StatefulWidget {   const callapi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override   State<callapi> createState() => _callapiState(); }
>
> class _callapiState extends State<callapi> {
>
>   List<dynamic> data = [];
>
>   final uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
>
>   void postdata()async{    final responce = await post(Uri.parse(uri),body:{
>       "title": "Anything",
>       "body": "Post body",
>       "userid": "1",
>     });    print(responce.body);
>
>   } @override   void initState() {
>     // TODO: implement initState
>     super.initState();
>     apidata();   }   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       body: Center(
>         child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: postdata, child: Text('send data'),),
>       )
>     );   }   void apidata()async{
>     final responce = await get(Uri.parse(uri));
>     final jsondata = jsonDecode(responce.body) as List;
>     setState(() {
>       data = jsondata;
>     });   } }
> ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).